# Asking similar questions - process?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I would like to ask a question on SO. However, a search reveals that a similar question has been asked, and I feel my question would get marked as a duplicate. The similar question has few answers - one of which is the accepted answer; and this answer is not the one I am looking for (i.e. it's a strategy change rather than a real solution to the answer).

I am very motivated to get an answer to this question - and thus would like to drive forward responses; possibly by offering a decent sized bounty.

Should I simply ask my question, or is it possible to get "ownership" of the similar question?

Comment: Possible dupes: [How does “Questions with similar titles” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108497), [Detecting similarity between questions : How?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60468).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your question isn't an exact duplicate, you should include that you saw that question in your search and explain why the question or answers are different from what you seek. Most people are reasonable and as long as you demonstrate due diligence in finding potential duplicates you should be fine.

Of course, if it's an *exact* duplicate, this won't be enough, so in that case it's best to bump the original and see if you can get some fresh answers.

Comment: please define "bump"

Comment: @Leon: Editing (even trivially) the post will put it back on the front page. If you can't do this, try posting an answer and deleting it.

Comment: @KyleCronin The latter seems very bad advice. Answering in order to bump the question and then delete it will not be tolerated.