# Any exceptions in duplicating questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asking similar questions - process?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/asking-similar-questions-process)

Again a possible duplicate. ;)

Lets say I have a question and I want to ask it in SO. I see a duplicate but I cannot find a successful answer there. (due to any reason... perhaps it may not get the attention etc.. ) So that Q & A is not important to me.

In such scenarios can I duplicate the question?

[An example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346062/digitally-communicate-with-usb-closed)

Comment: Not a good example. Dupe is from the same author.

Comment: Also that question was closed as a duplicate as fast as it was asked :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/asking-similar-questions-process

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the context and will be evaluated per question. Whether the original has an accepted answer is not often a criteria used for closing a duplicate. If the question and the context is the same as the other, and it does not have an answer, posting a duplicate is definitely not going to ensure it will get one.

Your best option would be to favorite the original and keep coming back to it.

Comment: But it will not get the user attention right? You are not going to move to page 7233 and answer a question there ;)

Comment: Bumping a question to give it attention is not accepted behavior unless the edit is to add something new to the question. It is covered in the FAQ here on Meta often. Very few users navigate the site based on pages, most use the Tags and RSS feeds, in which case who knows what page the question is on. **Point is if someone had an answer the question would have an accepted answer**.