# Specific questions that can't be closed as duplicates because duplicates now have to have an answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

> Now that this is live, we're especially interested in *examples* of things you'd like to close as dupe but can't now.

(Quoting David Fullerton♦)

> With that said, **this is still experimental** -- if it's breaking the site we can always remove the requirement for an answer.

Backstory:

- Recent changes to close as duplicate [part deux](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux#comment488329_166707) and [part un](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165933/changes-to-close-as-duplicate?lq=1) for information about the change (principally, you can only close as duplicate of something with an answer).
- [We should be able to close questions as duplicates of any question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165928/we-should-be-able-to-close-questions-as-duplicates-of-any-question?lq=1) **where you can discuss *whether* the change is a good thing**, and look at [shog's list of old close-as-duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165936/194906) for inspiration.

Here I'd like to know about specific questions

- that you'd like to close as a duplicate today (and they're not already closed)
- but there are *no* answered duplicates,
- and the question shouldn't be closed for another reason (it's a real, constructive, on-topic question that's not too localized)

(If the best answer to close-as-duplicate to has no votes, please explain why it's *not* useful, i.e. why you shouldn't upvote it.)

Are there instances of this blowing up in the past? (Is there a network of copies of a *never-answered* real, constructive, on-topic question that's not too localized?) Please check carefully that there are no answers, because some answers means that you *could* close as a duplicate, or that you *shouldn't* close as duplicate (if the answer doesn't fit the other question).

This is how we can monitor any additional clutter generated by the new rule.

It's important that you give *specific examples*, rather than hypothetical ones - there's plenty of those in the linked questions. This is about evidence, not arguments please.

Answer (score 3):

[This question on AU](https://askubuntu.com/q/257011/44179) should be closed as a duplicate of [this older question about it](https://askubuntu.com/q/217312/44179).

I don't want to upvote the one answer it has because it's just links to the forums.

Now of course it might be a better idea to dupe the older one to the newer one, but we can't do that either.

Comment: Update: It was closed 7.5 hours after it was asked as a dupe of what appears to be [a _very_ helpful answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-where-to-start-troubleshooting), which is better for future visitors to the site.

Comment: That's crazy...  *shrug*.

Comment: OK, maybe I didn't read deeply enough; the forums seemed to be suggesting ndiswrapper, in contradiction of the advice in the general troubleshooting guide. I take back "better for future vistors" and replace it with "might be useful to future visitors". They still have a link in a comment to the answer you didn't want to upvote, so they can still get that advice too.

Comment: Hang on a minute - you were one of the close voters to that general troubleshooter!

Comment: @AndrewC I'm afraid there isn't a way to prove this, but I don't think I voted to close it as a dupe.  That just doesn't make sense.

Comment: It says "marked as duplicate by George Edison, Eliah Kagan, Eric Carvalho, Seth, LnxSlck Feb 17 at 3:04" The "Seth" links to the profile of a man who looks very much like you, if your profile on meta is anything to go by.

Comment: @AndrewC  It takes 5 close votes to close a question, no matter what the individuals voted to close as, the majority rules.  In other words if I voted "Too Localized" and 4 other voted "Dupe" it'd be duped.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, that's true. I think your voting isn't the issue though, so I shouldn't have brought it up anyway.

Comment: And now I see the question, has only 300 something hits, 1 answer breaking redirection... no good as signpost, deleting......

Answer (score 1):

[This older question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/36010/105) has no answer.

[This duplicate new question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/56278/how-to-display-only-leading-spaces-in-whitespace-mode) cannot be closed.

Seems wrong to me.  And if repeated we can have any number of such duplicate questions, until someone provides an answer.  What would make sense is to have *one* such question.

Answer (score 0):

See
[Visual studio Intellitest execution through command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885783/visual-studio-intellitest-execution-through-command-line)
and
[Intellitest command line invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549021/intellitest-command-line-invocation)

They're same question with the same answer.

People do not want to upvote because it is not the answer that they want to hear.