# How to handle duplicate questions when old one is not accepted

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Since the [changes in closing](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/), no question can be marked duplicate if the old question doesn't have approved or upvoted answer.

Now there was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922189/is-there-any-way-to-add-cookie-in-method-with-responsebody-annotationspring-m) that is 100% identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677842/is-there-any-way-to-add-cookie-in-method-with-responsebody-annotation), but still it cannot be marked as duplicate since the old one hasn't got accepted or upvoted answer, even though it probably has the right answer. What's the correct process to respond to this?

I went though discussion related to new behaviour, but not a suggestion how one should react when the situation does occur. Should I vote to merge? Just comment about the duplicate? Leave it as it is? Upvote the answer in the original question even though I'm not sure if it is worth it, just to be able to flag the duplicate?

Related:

- [Changes to "close as duplicate" (part deux)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux)
- [We should be able to close questions as duplicates of any question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165928/we-should-be-able-to-close-questions-as-duplicates-of-any-question)

Comment: I upvoted the original question's answer. Mark duplicate as desired.

Comment: Work-around: upvote that one answer. It only needs one upvote..

Comment: Bad general workaround, though. Lots of duplicate questions are also *bad* questions to which good answers are not necessarily posted.

Comment: marked now. However, I would be interested to know about the general process of how one should react.