# Unanswered question count

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions, unanswered-questions, duplicate-answers

To mark an question duplicate in Stack Overflow we are using the below flag:

> a duplicate...
>
> **This question has been asked before and already has an answer.**

Is there a flag to mark a question as duplicate which are in the "unanswered" list and the same like new question was answered (with accepted)?

> a duplicate...
>
> **This question again / repeatedly / newly asked and answered.**

So that we can get a proper report of each question's flag of Stack Overflow

Comment: To flag duplicate that question must have answer.You cannot mark as duplicate with unanswered question.

Comment: So is there any way to decrease the count of the unanswered question, which are answered newly as separate question?

Comment: @James thanks But I could not marked duplicate with unanswered question. I will try again.

Comment: No, there isn't such flag and [request to remove the requirement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165928/we-should-be-able-to-close-questions-as-duplicates-of-any-question?lq=1) has been declined.