# How does "Questions with similar titles" work?

Tags: discussion, search, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting similarity between questions : How?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60468/detecting-similarity-between-questions-how)

I would like to get the basic idea how this is implemented and how the algorithm works, particularly the way it makes suggestions in real time. A keyword or a link would suffice.

Comment: Interesting question. I seem to get better results from this functionality than I do from searching for my question's title.